Impossible to install my Android App on tablet
Here you are a piece of manifest:
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<!-- Which permission (from version 6) must be asked to user the first using time:
    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous -->
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE"/>-->
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK"/>-->
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_HEALTH"/>-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>

    <!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false"/>
    <!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices.
             If your app doesn't use Bluetooth scan results to derive physical
             location information, you can strongly assert that your app
             doesn't derive physical location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:required="false"/>
    <!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth
      devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" android:required="false"/>
    <!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
           devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" android:required="false"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT" android:required="false"/>

    <!-- Remove this permission asked by Facebook SDK -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />

    <!--<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />-->
    <!--<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />-->
    <!--<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />-->

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!--https://developer.android.com/reference/android/health/connect/HealthPermissions-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_HEIGHT" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_WEIGHT" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_STEPS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_SLEEP" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_TOTAL_CALORIES_BURNED" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_EXERCISE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.WRITE_HEIGHT" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.WRITE_WEIGHT" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.WRITE_TOTAL_CALORIES_BURNED" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.WRITE_EXERCISE" android:required="false" />

From any tablet, I can't install my App available from Google Play. From my mobile phone, there is no problem.
Thank you very much for your advices,

You should better analyze your built APK to see the final merged AndroidManifest.xml. Every used library can add entries to your manifest.
